# Ajax CORS Issue: If I use no-cors, the Authorization header disappears

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making an ajax call using fetch. When I use no-cors, the Authorization header disappears. If I use cors, the Authorization header is there, but I get cors error. I want to disable cors (no-cors), but it I get 401 (unauthorized) error since the Authorization header inexplicably disappears. Thx

```
fetch("https:...", {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "no-cors",
    withCredentials: true,
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzaW5nYXB1QE1GQ0dELkNPTSIsImlzcyI6IktlcmJlcm9zUHJvdmlkZXIiLCJhdWQiOiJLZXJiZXJvc1Byb3ZpZGVyIiwicHJlZmVycmVkX3VzZXJuYW1lIjoic2luZ2FwdUBNRkNHRC5DT00iLCJraWQiOjEyNjMsImV4cCI6MTYxMTE1MzI4NCwiaWF0IjoxNjExMTEwMDg0fQ.Dz5vQfwZoU-bIzWJ8lsY1T_dHIqwGyL9rZxM8eG4n74"
      }
    })
   .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Comment: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#simple-header

Comment: Why would you use `no-cors`? Its practical uses are few

Comment: bro' if I dont use no-cors, I get a cors error. The url I am using is not in my control.

Comment: Hey @epascrello thx for reply. Issue is, if I use no-cors, Authorization header disappears as see from debugger, due to which there is an expected 401 Unauthorized.